# JQgrid with div element instead of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Can we use Jquery JQgrid with div element instead of table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't replace `<table>` to `<div>`.

The problem is that the code of jqGrid really work with the content of the grid as with the table. The DOM representation of `<tr>` element has `cells` and `rowIndex` properties (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_tablerow.asp) for example), the `<table>` has `rows` property (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp)) which supports `namedItem` method (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp)) and so on. The usage of methods which are specific for `<table>` **improves performance** of jqGrid code.

In any way the code of jqGrid really uses that main element of jqGrid is `<table>` and not `<div>`. So the code of jqGrid contains the following lines (see [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L926-929))

```
if(this.tagName.toUpperCase()!='TABLE') {
    alert("Element is not a table");
    return;
}
```

In other words if you would use come other element (like `<div>`) instead of `<table>` you would get error message with the text "Element is not a table" instead of displaying the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I think that jqgrid plugin has been created to design tables via jquery, so it will be a bit strange using it to design div instead of tables